# M.2 SSD is not showing as a bootable drive on Asus f510ua Vivobook

Tags: windows, ssd

I have an Asus f510ua Vivobook laptop, and I upgrading to a 500GB M.2 SSD. When I placed the SSD in the slot, and booted to the HDD, it was detected  completely fine. I then proceeded to clone Windows 10 from the HDD to the SSD, and once again everything seemed to work. When I boot the drive from the other hard drive, the SSD is readable, and when I explore the data on the SSD it appears to have been cloned correctly.

When I enter the BIOS, the device is not shown as a boot option, however it is visible as a storage device in the BIOS. Is this an indication that the cloned software doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Have you cloned the EFI partition as well?

Comment: Ended up sorting it out, turns out it was just the cloning software being dodgy, ended up redoing the clone with different software and it worked out fine! Thanks